# While logging weird string using NLog: ArgumentException: 'illegal characters in path.'

Tags: c#, special-characters, nlog, argumentexception

I'm trying to log the following string in a logfile:

```
$"{(char)0}{(char)1}{(char)3}{(char)0}{(char)3}{(char)0}{(char)0}{(char)0}{Line}{(char)0}{(char)7}{(char)232}{(char)3}{(char)0}{(char)9}{(char)31}"
```

Where `Line` equals `"        59    "`. (the integer value can change but not the length (10))

When looking at that string in the watch-window, this is what I see:

[image]

Some information about my `NLog` configuration (according to the watch-window):

```
((System.RuntimeType)_log._loggerType).AssemblyQualifiedName : 
"NLog.Logger, NLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=..."   

_log._loggerType.IsUnicodeClass : false
...
```

What can I do in order to avoid the mentioned `Exception` when launching `Log.Debug($"Commands=[{Commands}]")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by a stupid mistake: at the beginning of my class, I had the following declaration:

```
private static readonly Logger _log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

So, instead of doing `Log.Debug()`, I needed to do `_log.Debug()`.